# Add text before or after an HTML element

Tags: javascript, html

If i have an HTML element like `<div>` with some text inside or another elements can I add before or after this div some text data without an html element, just plain text?

I'd like to use only pure Javascript.

Something like :

```
<div id="parentDiv">
   my text must be added here
  <div id="childDiv"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Yes, you can create a text node with [`document.createTextNode('the text')`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM:document.createTextNode)

Then you can insert it like an element, with appendChild or insertBefore.

Example that insert a text before #childDiv:

```
var text = document.createTextNode('the text');
var child = document.getElementById('childDiv');
child.parentNode.insertBefore(text, child);
```

Comment: You could also try the "insertAdjacentText" or "insertAdjacentHTML" methods: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.insertAdjacentHTML

Answer (score 31):

Just for the record:

```
div.insertAdjacentHTML( 'beforeBegin', yourText );
```

where `div` is your child-DIV.

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/ZkzDk/

Comment: You can also add it after...
div.insertAdjacentHTML( 'afterEnd', 'my text added after' );
Does anyone know if you can remove it? (without using a class or id)

Comment: @tkerwood Sure. You need to retrieve a reference to that *Text* node and then use the `.removeChild()` method (on its parent).

Answer (score 10):

If you just need text, I find that [`element.insertAdjacentText(position, text)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentText) is flexible for many scenarios and is also compatible with older browsers like IE6. Where `position` is exactly where you want the text to be and `text` is the text node or just a string. The options are:

- `'beforebegin'` Before the element itself.
- `'afterbegin'` Just inside the element, before its first child.
- `'beforeend'` Just inside the element, after its last child.
- `'afterend'` After the element itself.

Like this:

```
let div = document.getElementById('parentDiv');
div.insertAdjacentText('afterbegin', 'My Plain Text..');
```

Answer (score 3):

In regards to the topic and the users question for inserting before or **after**, here is an example for after:

```
   var text = document.createTextNode("my text must be added here.");
   var childTag = document.getElementById("childDiv");

   childTag.parentNode.insertBefore(text, childTag.nextSibling);
```

If the childTag does not have any siblings, it is okay because the insertBefore method handles this case and simply adds it as the last child.

Also can possibly use the appendChild() method after creating text node then add your childTag via the parentNode.

Answer (score 1):

You can add text node. Create node - `document.createTextNode('text')` and then insert/append/replace - do whatever you want.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should do it:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var parent = document.getElementById('parentDiv');
  var sibling = document.getElementById('childDiv');
  var text = document.createTextNode('new text');
  parent.insertBefore(text, sibling);
</script>
```