# Managing No Man's Land in a content editable editor

Tags: javascript, html, contenteditable, caret

**Background:**

My program offers smart brace completion, that is automatic addition of a `]` on typing a `[`.

**Problem:**

Consider this scenario:

[image]

Notice the editor on the left where the caret is placed. As you can see in the Inspect Element on the right, the caret is placed right between two consecutive `<br>`s. There is no text node or element node between them. The caret belongs to neither of the `<br>`s. It is a no-man's land. What is surprising is that the caret belongs to the parent editor!

[image]

Above you can see `range.startContainer` and `range.endContainer` both point to the parent content editable editor `div.editor.show`. Also, the second print line that mentions `2` is the caret position that I got using `range.startOffset`. I have a faint guess that the `2` refers to one text node and one `<br>` that precede the caret.

**What happens due to problem:**

The second `]` that has to be inserted after `[` gets inserted at the second index in the entire `div.editor`, meaning right after `Th` at the beginning. So, after I locate my caret in the no-man's land and press `[`, this happens:

[image]

**Question:**

How am I supposed to **detect and provide a fix** for this no-man's land problem?

**[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/buj9gauu/1/)**

<sup>*Note: this does not occur in `<textarea>`s.*</sup>

Comment: First, I'd recommend you to add a fiddle if it's possible so that we can play with the issue and try our guesses/recomendations. Second, have you tried to insert zero-width space/nbsp after a `<br>` when it is created/inserted?

Comment: @YakovL I've added the fiddle. But suppose the `<br>` was present in the text beforehand. Then, it's no use checking if a br was created or inserted.

Comment: Why, you can add those symbols on load, too.. (and append text nodes http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7378097/add-text-before-or-after-an-html-element after http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4793604/how-to-do-insert-after-in-javascript-without-using-a-library each one)

Comment: Ok, I understand, I can do `.querySelector` to check for two consecutive `<br>`s and then insert an `&nbsp;` between them? But I don't want to modify what the user is writing. So, how about inserting an empty text node instead?

Comment: I'm not sure if you can put cursor into an *empty* text node, but you can try (it where zero-width space is used by some browsers). By the way, have you considered using Medium.js? I've read their article about ContentEditable (https://medium.engineering/why-contenteditable-is-terrible-122d8a40e480) recently and it sounds like your issue is one of the many that their lib addresses

Comment: Ok, now I know more about ranges and selections and I think I know how to fix this. But for not to write some "guess answer", please add the auto-completion code to your fiddle so that I can test my idea. You should probably show it here anyway.