# Is it possible with vanilla js to dynamically add a button element next to a text node?

Tags: javascript, html

For a todo list, I'm trying to dynamically add a button as a child of a list element and a sibling of a text node as below.

```
<ul>
  <li>Hello world <button>X</button></li>
</ul>
```

The unordered list is in the HTML file but the list, text and button need to be inserted dynamically from the JS file. Is this possible without wrapping the text in a p tag?

Here's the code:

```js
const todoInputEl = document.querySelector(".todo__input");
const todoListEl = document.querySelector(".todo__list");
const todoItemEls = document.querySelector(".todo__item");
const deleteItemEl = document.querySelector(".done");

function addListItem() {
  todoInputEl.addEventListener("keypress", function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode === 13) {
      let newListItem = createListItem(todoInputEl.value);
      todoListEl.insertBefore(newListItem, todoListEl.childNodes[0]);
      todoInputEl.value = "";
    }
  })
}

function createListItem(text) {
  const deleteButton = document.createElement("button");
  const newListElement = document.createElement("li");
  const newParaElement = document.createElement("p");

  deleteButton.setAttribute("type", "button");
  deleteButton.classList.add("delete");
  deleteButton.innerHTML = "&times;";

  newListElement.appendChild(newParaElement);
  newListElement.setAttribute("class", "todo__item");

  newParaElement.setAttribute("class", "todo__p");
  newParaElement.textContent = text;

  newParaElement.parentNode.insertBefore(deleteButton, deleteButton.nextElementSibling);

  return newListElement;
}

addListItem();
```

```html
<main>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="todo">
      <div class="todo__header">
        <h1 class="todo__title">to dos</h1>
        <label for="todo input">
           <input type="text" class="todo__input" placeholder="enter a thing to do">
        </label>
      </div>
      <div class="todo__body">
        <ul class="todo__list">

        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</main>
```

As you see, it works if the text is inside a p tag, but I can't get it to work insert to the same place if it's just a plain text node. I looked extensively for examples of this being done, but haven't found any yet.

Comment: Yes, it's possible, but the posted question does not appear to include [any attempt](https://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/) at all to solve the problem. StackOverflow expects you to [try to solve your own problem first](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users), as your attempts help us to better understand what you want. Please edit the question to show what you've tried, so as to illustrate a specific problem you're having in a [MCVE]. For more information, please see [ask] and take the [tour].

Comment: "text and button need to be inserted dynamically from the JS file" - What js file? How is the data represented in the file? Is "Hello world" coming from this js file?

Comment: everything is possible with vanilla JS

Comment: @JonP - True, hopefully the pen answers the questions. I was trying to keep it concise. I actually want to use an event listener to target the whole li. But if there's a p inside, it creates a hole over the p. It only triggers around the edges over the li. Possibly this is something to do with bubbling vs capture? Don't know if I'm on the right track...

Comment: Based only on your example code, this seems to be a duplicate of [Add text before or after an HTML element](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7378097/215552). Stack Overflow questions should contain all information necessary to solve the problem **in the question itself** not only on an external site.

Comment: @HereticMonkey Sure, you could say that, but my question is around inserting a button not text (even though text is also successfully inserted). And in the question you reference there is very little info - it's almost identical in form to what I posted. The difference is, that people answered that question instead of pedantically picking apart my sincere question or offering useless statements. I tried putting the code in my question, but the formatting was so awkward I moved it off site. I think you guys are missing the golden rule here. Helping.

Comment: The takeaway from the duplicate is the use of `insertAdjacentHTML`. Have you tried using that method? There are links to documentation if it is unfamiliar. I'm not sure how that is not helpful. If you feel any comment is useless, click the flag icon next to the comment and flag it as such. The golden rule is generally described by the phrase "do unto others what you would have done unto you"; I expect people to tell me when I have done something that makes it harder for volunteers to answer a question I am asking.

Comment: Help us to help you by putting everything we need in the question itself. The more effort you put into posing and formatting your question, the more effort people will put into your answer. A [MCVE] in the question is always looked upon favorably

Comment: @HereticMonkey I'm not a veteran of this forum, so I have a lot to learn. I did try `insertAdjacentHTML`. I knew of that question before I posted mine.  It's a complex problem with a lot of things going on, so I'm having trouble tracking everything - like a bundle of knots. I thought it was a simple question, but the dynamic aspect confuses me a lot. My def of golden rule here is a basic principle which should always be followed to ensure success in general or in a particular activity. The platinum rule helps with understanding this in an interpersonal sense. :/

Comment: @JonP Copy that. I'm trying.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DOM manipulation can be expensive ([jQuery DOM manipulations - performance comparation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7460727/jquery-dom-manipulations-performance-comparation)). Using `innerHTML` sidesteps this and in my opinion makes things simpler.

```js
const todoInputEl = document.querySelector(".todo__input");
const todoListEl = document.querySelector(".todo__list");
const todoItemEls = document.querySelector(".todo__item");
const deleteItemEl = document.querySelector(".done");

function addListItem() {
  todoInputEl.addEventListener("keypress", function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode === 13) {

      todoListEl.innerHTML += createListItem(todoInputEl.value);
    }
  })
}

function createListItem(text) {
  let listTemplate = "<li>{{ToDo}} <button type='button' class='delete'>&times;</button></li>";

  return listTemplate.replace("{{ToDo}}", text);
}

addListItem();
```

```html
<main>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="todo">
      <div class="todo__header">
        <h1 class="todo__title">to dos</h1>
        <label for="todo input">
            <input type="text" class="todo__input" placeholder="enter a thing to do">
        </label>
      </div>
      <div class="todo__body">
        <ul class="todo__list">

        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</main>
```